# In Apollo Nuxt, how do I access the non-default client in a method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, shopify, nuxt.js, apollo

I'm using Apollo in a Nuxt app. I'm trying to use my non-default client (Shopify) in a method. Something like this ideally:

In my `nuxt.config.js` I have Apollo setup like this:

```
apollo: {
    clientConfigs: {
        default: {
            httpEndpoint:
                "http://example.com",
            tokenName: "apollo-token",
            persisting: false,
            websocketsOnly: false
        },
        shopify: {
            httpEndpoint:
                "http://example.shopify.com",
            tokenName: "apollo-token"
            ... etc...
        }
    }
}
```

And then in my component, I have this method:

```
methods: {
        createCheckout() {
            this.$apollo.getClient("shopify")
                .mutate({
                    mutation: this.checkoutQuery,
                    variables: {
                        variantId: this.selectedProduct.variantId,
                        quantity: this.selectedProduct.quantity
                    }
                })
        }
}}
```

This doesn't work, because `getClient()` only returns the default client (WordPress in this case). So how do I get access to the other client in a method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! The answer is this:

```
methods: {
        createCheckout() {
            this.$apollo.provider.clients.shopify
                .mutate({
                    mutation: this.checkoutQuery,
                    variables: {
                        variantId: this.selectedProduct.variantId,
                        quantity: this.selectedProduct.quantity
                    }
                })
        }
}}
```